# Appearance of other quantifiers in rules of conversion to prenex normal form.

Tags: first-order-logic

Take the following conversion to prenex normal form rule (as described in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form)):

> $ \left (\forall x \phi \right )\wedge\psi $  is equivalent to $\forall x \left(\phi \wedge \psi \right)$, provided $x$ does not appear as a free variable in $\psi$.

My background is from reading through Velleman's *How To Prove It* and trying to prove statements involving quantifiers via "mechanical" equivalences and not via the more "textual" techniques explained in the book. Velleman in general is very light on the *logic*, presumably because he's trying to introduce the bare minimum required to be "eloquent" in proof reading and writing, and not what would be necessary to understand what a proof is and how it works at a more fundamental and theoretical level, but I digress.

The **question** is, in the rule above, can the $\psi$ formula contain other quantifiers, as long as it does not contain $x$ as a free variable? For example, suppose $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are families of sets. Can

$$\forall y \left[\forall A \left(A\notin\mathcal{F} \vee y \notin A \right) \wedge \exists B \left( B\in\mathcal{G}\wedge y \in B \right) \right]$$

be replaced with

$$\forall y \forall A \left[\left(A \notin \mathcal{F} \vee y \notin A \right) \wedge \exists B \left( B\in\mathcal{G}\wedge y \in B \right) \right]$$

if we let $\exists B \left( B\in\mathcal{G}\wedge y \in B \right)$ take the role of $\psi$ and $A$ take the role of $x$, noting that $A$ does not appear as a free variable in the former?

My intuition says no, since then through a couple of additional manipulations we could conclude that the following formulas are also equivalent:

$$\forall y \forall A \exists B \left[\left(A\notin\mathcal{F} \vee y \notin A \right) \wedge  \left( B\in\mathcal{G}\wedge y \in B \right) \right]$$

$$\forall y \exists B \forall A \left[\left(A\notin\mathcal{F} \vee y \notin A \right) \wedge  \left( B\in\mathcal{G}\wedge y \in B \right) \right]$$

So this would imply that the order of $\forall A$ and $\exists B$ does not matter, which  doesn't sound right, but I'd like to get a more grounded answer.

Comment: Your example is not very clear to me... but, in general YES: $\psi$ can be for example $\exists y \chi$ and still holds that $(∀x \varphi) ∧ \exists y \chi$ is equivalent to : $∀x (\varphi ∧ \exists y \chi)$, provided that $x$ is not free in $\chi$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for answering. I have revised the question so hopefully what I'm asking becomes more evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we have :

> $\forall x\varphi(x) \land \psi \equiv \forall x(\varphi(x) \land \psi) \, \,$, provided that $x$ is not *free* in $\psi$;

but also :

> $\sigma \land \exists y \chi(y) \equiv \exists y (\sigma \land \chi(y)) \, \,$, provided that $y$ is not *free* in $\sigma$.

THus, we can "Add" the two cases having :

> > $\forall x\varphi(x) \land \exists y \chi(y) \equiv \forall x \exists y (\varphi(x) \land \chi(y))$.

Your concern - it seems to me - is : may I "switch" the quantifiers ? In general no, but in this case yes, because the quantified variables are "separated".

Consider the simple example :

> $\forall x(x \ge 0) \land \exists y (y=0)$

According to the above rules, it is equivalent to :

> $\forall x \exists y [(x \ge 0) \land (y=0)]$;

we can easily check that, for any $n \in \mathbb N$, it is enough to choose $0$ as value for $y$ and we have that :

> $n \ge 0 \land 0=0$

is satisfied in $\mathbb N$.

But the same holds for : $\exists y \forall x [(x \ge 0) \land (y=0)]$; in order to satisfy it, it is enough to choose $0$ for $y$, and the formula will be satisfied for any $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. This gives me more confidence to tackle certain problems though the more I read about this the more I want to study logic into more detail. It seems like Enderton's *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* might be good. Do you have any opinion on it?

Comment: @MuchToLearn - it is **very** good. You can see also Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&printsec=frontcover) (2007) : simpler, or Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&printsec=frontcover) (5th ed - 2013) : more topics covered.